# "myMap is not a function" error when using the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, google-maps

I know this has been asked before. But the situation is that I'm referring the function before loading the map api.

This was working a few days ago, and started giving me this error out of nowhere. I'd be grateful if someone could help me.

Error:

[image]

```
    //HTML

    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script>

        var markers = [];

        function myMap() {

            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.7312983, -7.5951745),
                zoom: 5
            };

            var image = 'https://imgur.com/9SsOEZu.png';
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'), mapProp);
            

            //Some PHP
        }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_key&callback=myMap">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Take your function out of the document ready function. It makes no sense to have it there + your are missing a closing `}`. Any decent IDE or online code editor should warn you about that.

Comment: My bad, I have to clean the code before posting here

Comment: So what doesn't work now? As posted, the code you shared does not trigger the error you mentioned. You need to provide a [mcve]. As a side note, you should restrict your API key (and not post it on public websites like this one until you do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it. The problem had nothing to do with Google Maps API but with a badly inputed value in the database that caused the code to crash before loading any JS.